# Rename Google Drive File returning null

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm renaming a Google Drive File with the GD SDK for Android with following code:

```
File file = new File();
file.setTitle(mNewName);
Files.Patch patchRequest = service.files().patch(mId, file);
patchRequest.setFields("title");
mUpdatedFile = patchRequest.execute();
```

The documentation says that .execute() should return a File object, it does, but in this File only the patched property is populated, all other fields are null. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying that you only want "title" to be returned:

```
patchRequest.setFields("title");
```

This fields parameter controls what will be populated.  You want the minimum necessary here, as its a lot more efficient.